# Prove that $X\oplus Y$ is a Dedekind cut

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a Dedekind cut. Now let $X\oplus Y=\{x+y\mid x\in X,y\in Y\}$. Show that $X\oplus Y$ is again a Dedekind cut. i.e. it must fulfill the following conditions:

> i) $X\oplus Y\not=\emptyset\;$ and $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\left(X\oplus Y\right)\not=\emptyset$
>
> ii) Let $x\in X\oplus Y$ and $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $r<x$, then $r\in X\oplus Y\;$ must follow.
>
> iii) $X\oplus Y$ has no maximum.

---

I was able to prove $X\oplus Y\not=\emptyset$ by contradiction, however, I'm kind of stuck with anything else. For example, if I try to contradict $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\left(X\oplus Y\right)\not=\emptyset$ I end up with this:

Proof by contradiction. Let $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\left(X\oplus Y\right)=\emptyset$.
$\Rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{x+y\mid x\in X,y\in Y\}=\emptyset\\\Rightarrow\{x+y\mid x\in X,y\in Y\}=\mathbb{Q}$

To prove equality, we must show $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \left(X\oplus Y\right)$ and $\left(X\oplus Y\right)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$.

1. $\left(X\oplus Y\right)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$: We know $X\subset Q$ and $Y\subset Q$.  (what now??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: To show that $\Bbb Q\setminus(X\oplus Y)\ne\varnothing$, show that there are $r\in\Bbb Q\setminus X$ and $s\in\Bbb Q\setminus Y$ such that $r,s\ge 0$, and then show that $x+y<r+s$ for each $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

For (ii), suppose that $r\in\Bbb Q$ and $r<z\in X\oplus Y$. By definition there are $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ such that $z=x+y$; let $d=z-r$.

- Is $d\in\Bbb Q$? Is $y-d\in Y$? How can you make use of this to show that $r\in X\oplus Y$?

For (iii), suppose that $X\oplus Y$ has a maximum element $z$; there are $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ such that $z=x+y$. Get a contradiction by showing that $x$ must be the maximum element of $X$.